# Why does input field get only the viewed text?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I know it might sounds stupid but I have an input field, in my C# script I get it using this

```
 public Text emailInput;
 public string email = emailInput.text;
```

but let's say I got my email ' calin.onaca@icloud.com '.
If after I write the email and it only display ' calin.onaca@icloud.co' or 'alin.calin@icloud.com' because of font size it might not display all the text which is fine, but the code receives only the displayed text.
Is it normal? How can I get all text not only the displayed one.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is a standard Unity InputField, you'll want to use that type instead.

```
public InputField emailInput;

var email = emailInput.text;
```

If you try to grab just the inner Text child of the InputField, you'll see inconsistent results.

Comment: If this helped you, please accept it as the answer.